# How to make the pandas multi-index data frame a simple table with only one column rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I was comparing SQL to Pandas from the website http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html then I found that the result of groupby functions are different in pandas and sql.

For example:
In pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/master/pandas/tests/data/tips.csv')
df.head()

g = df.groupby(['smoker', 'day']).agg({'tip': [np.size, np.mean]})
print(g)
```

Gives:

```
             tip          
             size      mean
smoker day                 
No     Fri    4.0  3.187500
       Sat   45.0  3.361556
       Sun   57.0  3.386491
       Thur  45.0  3.122667
Yes    Fri   15.0  3.114000
       Sat   41.0  3.048049
       Sun   19.0  3.595789
       Thur  17.0  3.030000
```

How to get the output as like given by SQL?

```
  smoker   day  tip_size  tip_mean
0     No   Fri         4  2.812500
1     No   Sat        45  3.102889
2     No   Sun        57  3.167895
3     No  Thur        45  2.673778
4    Yes   Fri        15  2.714000
5    Yes   Sat        41  2.701707
6    Yes   Sun        19  3.516842
7    Yes  Thur        17  3.030000
```

Comment: Hi, have you looked into reset_index() method? This would solve the issue with the multi index. For the columns I would flatten using g.columns = g.columns.get_level(1) + '_' + g.get_level(0)

Comment: Thanks, I will keep an eye on that.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer.

```
g = g.reset_index()
print(g)
```

gives:

```
  smoker   day   tip          
                size      mean
0     No   Fri   4.0  2.812500
1     No   Sat  45.0  3.102889
2     No   Sun  57.0  3.167895
3     No  Thur  45.0  2.673778
4    Yes   Fri  15.0  2.714000
5    Yes   Sat  42.0  2.875476
6    Yes   Sun  19.0  3.516842
7    Yes  Thur  17.0  3.030000
```

Now, `g.column.values` gives:

```
array([('smoker', ''), ('day', ''), ('tip', 'size'), ('tip', 'mean')],
      dtype=object)
```

Using, list comprehension we can get the required column names

```
g.columns = ['_'.join(e)  if e[1] else ''.join(e)  for e in g.columns.values]
print(g)
```

This gives:

```
  smoker   day  tip_size  tip_mean
0     No   Fri       4.0  2.812500
1     No   Sat      45.0  3.102889
2     No   Sun      57.0  3.167895
3     No  Thur      45.0  2.673778
4    Yes   Fri      15.0  2.714000
5    Yes   Sat      42.0  2.875476
6    Yes   Sun      19.0  3.516842
7    Yes  Thur      17.0  3.030000
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into `g.reset_index()` method.

This would solve the issue with the multi index.

For the columns I would suggest flatten using `get_level_values()` method

```
g.columns = g.columns.get_level_values(1) + '_' + g.get_level_values(0)
```

Also note from pandas group by documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

```
as_index : boolean, default True.
```

For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index. Only relevant for DataFrame input. `as_index=False` is effectively “SQL-style” grouped output

Comment: Gives: `AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'get_level'`

Comment: @user10735909 Apologies. `get_level_values()` is the [correct method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html)